# How to confirm the airline registered your USA departure correctly if leaving on a different passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Suppose I have the following scenario:

- Leaving Vietnam for USA. Registered with the airline using my Dominican Passport which has a valid US visa. Successfully did exit immigration with my EU passport which I used to successfully enter.
- Leaving USA for EU. Registered with the airline using my EU passport so that they know I can go to EU without a visa in my Dominican passport. I also show them my Dominican passport which I used to enter the US so that they can do the immigration exit procedure.

Given that the US is paperless when it comes to entry / exit, how can I confirm that the airline successfully did the paperwork for me?

Thank you!

Comment: This is covered in [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/19400) and [Couldn't return papers to border officials last time. Should I be afraid when going back to USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2026/19400).

Comment: I see what you’re saying but I think it’s a bit different and deserves a page on its own. The dual passport answer merely tells you it’s OK, not how to verify it. The other answer doesn’t necessarily tell you you are using a different passport and is more about how to correct a situation where you didn’t turn the paper I-94 in. What do you think?

Comment: PS — I simplified the question so it only answers the part that isn’t addressed in the other two directly.

Comment: Also see [How can I confirm that my I-94 form was correctly processed after leaving the US in 2007?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/48273/19400) and [Issues with US immigration after alleged overstay - how to handle?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17053/19400) and [How do I clear an incorrect red flag on my US visa for overstaying, when in fact my departure date has not been recorded in the database?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49393/19400).  I don't think the reason for the missed departure record is particularly significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can confirm that the airline processed you correctly by checking your passport records at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.